# Vagrant/virtualbox sleep timeout

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

How can I configure virtualbox through vagrant to sleep or halt the machine after some timeout?

Would be nicer to do it through `Vagrantfile`. If not possible, maybe some kind of bash command to provision the sleep timeout? I'm using ubuntu guest machine.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this as far as I know. It's also a bit of a strange request so I'd be interested in knowing **why** you want to do it.

1. You can add a provision script to your `Vagrantfile` that will shut the machine down after a certain amount of time from when you booted it.

   ```
   #shutdown after 1 hour (3600)
   $script = <<SCRIPT
   sleep 3600
   shutdown -h now
   SCRIPT

   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
   end
   ```
2. You can install `xscreensaver` to shut it down after a certain amount of idle time. The following code is from the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461066/391426) of another similar question:

> Using xscreensaver, I could manually specify what to do after a
>   certain amount of time of inactivity. To use xscreensaver, you need to
>   install it using:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
> ```
>
> or install it from the software center and then run it once using:
>
> ```
> xscreensaver-demo
> ```
>
> or type "xscreensaver" on the dash and open "Screensaver".
>
> This will create a `~/.xscreensaver` file. Open it and search for the
>   line:
>
> ```
> programs:                                                                     \
> ```
>
> and add:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff" boolean:true \n\
> ```
>
> just below the
>
> ```
> programs:                                                                     \
> ```
>
> line.
>
> You can specify the time after which shutdown should be triggered by
>   changing the line starting with `timout`. Modify it to
>
> ```
> timeout:        2:00:00
> ```
>
> to shutdown after two hours.
>
> Have a look at my `.xscreensaver` file [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7398678/).
>
> This should poweroff your machine after two hours of inactivity or
>   whatever time you specify in the script.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128481/how-do-i-set-xscreensaver-to-autostart) to see how to add xscreensaver on boot.
> - I tried using complex shutdown, but the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/complexshutdown/+bug/796721) seems to affect me so could not happen. Otherwise, a graphical application
>     would have been available for this.
> - This could be achieved using xautolock, however, as [redanimalwar](https://askubuntu.com/users/195243/redanimalwar) pointed, out a timout greater than 1 hour is not
>     possible without modifying its source code and recompiling.

---

**EDIT**

As per the OP's comments, if you want to shutdown a headless box after some type of inactivity conditions, [this article](http://oils-of-life.com/blog/linux/server/auto-shutdown-and-auto-suspending-a-linux-server/) is probably up your alley.

Note that you said the reason you want to do this is because you sometimes forget to halt the machine and it drains your battery. An obvious caveat of **idle** shutdown scripts is that if the box isn't idle, it won't shut it down... and if it **is idle** it probably isn't draining your battery. So if it were me, I would really focus on trying to remember to halt my machine when I wasn't using it if your battery is of primary concern, as programming is not likely able to solve this problem for you.

Comment: interesting about the #2 option - the downside of first option is that it hangs on the host after you run vagrant command - so you actually need to run vagrant up from one terminal, check to see that this provisioning will run and ssh from another terminal. I also wonder whats the purpose of doing this and I am pretty sure there are other options to answer what is needed not just what is asked here.

Comment: The problem is that, after I finish the work with the box, the box keeps being up and running. If I forget to halt it, eventually it drains the battery.

The first solution seems like will shutdown the machine, no matter what. I'll try the second option and write an update.

Comment: I'm running in headless mode, so, no xserver and I get the following error `xscreensaver-demo: 22:29:08: Gtk-warning: cannot open display:` when running `xscreensaver-demo` command.

Comment: the guide in the article looks promising. I'll try it asap and let you know. Thanks a lot!